# Reduce code redundancy

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, optimization

I have a rails application which has some following code

```
            <ul class="sortable grid row">
            <% @videouploads.each do |video_upload| %>
                <% if video_upload.category == 'モノナビ' && video_upload.priority == 1 %>
                    <%= render partial: 'adminrow', :locals => {:video_upload => video_upload } %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
```

I have to write this code 10 times for `video_upload.priority == 1` where priority changes from 1 to 10. How do I avoid code duplication or do I have what is the best solution ?

Comment: do it in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% (1..10).each do |inc| %>    
  <ul class="sortable grid row">
    <% @videouploads.each do |video_upload| %>
      <% if video_upload.category == 'モノナビ' && video_upload.priority == inc %>
      <%= render partial: 'adminrow', :locals => {:video_upload => video_upload } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

How about this ?

Answer (score 1):

loop over the priorities

```
<% priorities = (1..10).to_a %>
<% priorities.each do |priority| %>
  <ul class="sortable grid row">
    <% @videouploads.each do |video_upload| %>
      <% if video_upload.category == 'モノナビ' && video_upload.priority == priority %>
        <%= render partial: 'adminrow', :locals => {:video_upload => video_upload } %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```